# Слитно? Раздельно?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? Я не понимаю.

`Спагетти было недоварено / не доварено.`

Answer (score 3):

Правильно:

*Спагетти **было недоварено.*** *Резиновое какое-то, есть невозможно.*  Качественный признак.

*Спагетти **было не доварено**.* *Пришлось оставить кухню и заняться другими делами.* Незавершенное действие.

А. П. Чехов. Три года (1895). *Рис в пирожках **был недоварен,** от скатерти пахло мылом, прислуга громко стучала ногами.*

**[Мама недоварила макароны, но и не доварила суп.](https://dzen.ru/a/YERd9rhhPB27xYUX)**